# How do i retrieve page information from inside of Unity?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, dom

I need to communicate Unity WebAssemly with page in both directions.

This is how I execute Unity functions from page:

```
<script>
    var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "https://propper_url/Build/_Builds.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});

    function unityObjectFun(index)
    {
        gameInstance.SendMessage ("ObjectInstance", "objectFunctionName", index);
    }
</script>

<a onclick="unityObjectFun(1)">invoke</a>

<div class="webgl-content">
    <div id="gameContainer" myValue="need this to read from Unity"></div>
</div>
```

But how can I do in reverse. Is it possible to retrieve myValue from Unity.

Alternatively is it possible to notify page that Unity loaded scene and started playing it so I could send to it myValue?

Comment: Have you read the Unity3d resource for [WebGL: Interacting with browser scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)?

Comment: Yes. I just figured it out and solved the problem.

Comment: If you don't mind, would you post a solution to your issue for future searchers?

Comment: I have some trouble with returning string from extern function. I print value before return and it is valid but after return it appears the string is empty. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You may want to write that up as a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244384/how-to-run-page-javascript-from-unity

Answer (score 1):

To perform any JavaScript code on a page from the Unity WebAssembly there are two things required:

1. Create the Javascript code as plugin.
2. Import the code in Unity script.

The whole procedure is described in this guide: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html.

The plugin code must reside in Assets/Plugins/pluginname.jslib path (the extension is important) and have similar structure:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    Hello: function () {
        window.alert("Hello, world!");
    },
    HelloReturn: function () {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

To use it there is required import:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void Hello();

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string HelloReturn();

    void Start() {
        Hello();
        Debug.log(HelloReturn());
    }
}
```